# How to create property simmilar to checkBox checked?

Tags: c#, winforms

IDE: vs 2010, c# .net , winforms

Hi, I am creating a toggle button userControl which will be having ON and OFF state, also I have created a property which set the initial state of the button, (SAME as checkbox IsChecked).

```
public bool Checked
    {
        get { return isToggleOn; }
        set { isToggleOn = value;
        onPropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    private void onPropertyChanged()
    {          

        this.BackgroundImage = isToggleOn ? Properties.Resources.toggleOnMIUI : Properties.Resources.toggleOffMIUI;
        IsChecked = isToggleOn ? true : false;


    }
```

This is working, in design time, Now in form1 I have added this control and created OnClickEvent to check the current state:

```
private void ucTglOverStepping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ucTglOverStepping.Checked)
        {
           doWork = true; //do work is bool variable in form1.cs
        }
        else if (!ucTglOverStepping.Checked)
        {
            doWork = false;
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is when the toggle button is in on state it is going into else condition.

because onPropertyChanged()  is executing before this ucTglOverStepping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) function, is there any way to execute the onPropertyChanged() after the execution of ucTglOverStepping_Click() function, or any other technique to fix this issue.

PROBLEM Explanation:

Test Case 1: suppose the current state is ON

1. user clicked on Button -> it will go in off state (checked should become false, it should go in else condition of OnClickEvent. but checked is getting true.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to call function in `set;get;` of property

```
 public bool Checked
        {
            get
            {
                return isToggleOn;
            }
            set
            {
                onPropertyChanged();
                isToggleOn = value;
            }

        }
```

If `onPropertyChanged()` only call when you set/change value or `Checked` properties ..

In your function seems you set property again at last line .. so it call function recursive.. you not need to set `IsChecked` value again

```
private void onPropertyChanged()
{          

    this.BackgroundImage = isToggleOn ? Properties.Resources.toggleOnMIUI : Properties.Resources.toggleOffMIUI;
// not need this 
//    IsChecked = isToggleOn ? true : false;


}
```

and your Question is

```
private void ucTglOverStepping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ucTglOverStepping.Checked)
        {
           doWork = true; //do work is bool variable in form1.cs
        }
        else if (!ucTglOverStepping.Checked)
        {
            doWork = false;
        }
    }
```

when you get property value it run only first part it will not go to call 
`onPropertyChanged()'
it will run only

```
    public bool Checked
            {
                get
                {
                    return isToggleOn;
                }
}
```

**UPDATE**

it it sill confusing ..

but why you not use `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` Event ?

Comment: getting same problem, added problem test case.

Comment: Update reply-> because I am making toggle button instead of using checkBox, for UI look.